# Python - Extract text next sibling

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I got an issue whereby can't extract the next sibling text properly, always got `None`.

```
soup_details.find(text='COLOR').next_sibling
```

HTML

```
<div><strong>COLOR</strong></div>
<div>Electric Blue.</div>
```

Expected result

```
Electric Blue.
```

Comment: Well, the other div isn’t the next sibling. It’s the parent’s next sibling. (You can confirm that the result of find is the strong tag.)

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy then how to get color value?

Comment: There is no sibling of the text node that contains `COLOR`. `Electric Blue.` is 3 nodes up and two down again. In human terms: it's a Great Uncle.

Comment: Look for the parent node, then all iterate over all the children and look for the div after the one that contains 'COLOR' text. Obviously will only work if the structure is consistent.

Comment: How to get a parent: .parent; see here. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your element is not `div` but `COLOR` text, which is a `NavigableString` object. You need to go two nodes up (`strong` and `div`) and find a `div` next to it. Something like this can do the job:

```py
soup.find(text='COLOR').parent.parent.find_next('div').text  # Electric Blue.
```

Full example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div><strong>COLOR</strong></div>
<div>Electric Blue.</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find(text='COLOR').parent.parent.find_next('div').text)
```

Prints:

```
Electric Blue.
```

Answer (score 1):

*You could also do the following.*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div><strong>COLOR</strong></div>' \
       '<div>Electric Blue.</div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
element = soup.select('div:nth-of-type(2)')[0]
print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have BS 4.7.1 or above you can use this `css` selector.

```
print(soup.select_one('div:contains("COLOR")').find_next('div').text)
```

**Code**:

```
html='''<div><strong>COLOR</strong></div>
<div>Electric Blue.</div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('div:contains("COLOR")').find_next('div').text)
```